# ARM TrustZone development

Tags: embedded, arm, trustzone

I am wondering if anyone have any information on development boards where you can utilize ARM TrustZone? I have the BeagleBoard XM which uses TI's OMAP3530 with Cortex-A8 processor that supports trust zone, however TI confirmed that they have disabled the function on the board as it is a general purpose device.

Further research got me to the panda board which uses OMAP4430 but there is no response from TI and very little information on the internet. How do you learn how to use trust zone?

Best Regards
Mr Gigu

Comment: There's probably a better stackexchange forum for you to try with this than StackOverflow. Have suggested migrate to SuperUser, but there might be something more niche available.

Comment: @JonEgerton Nonsense, this a question about development, it's perfectly on-topic on SO. Questions about ARM boards would be off-topic on SU anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, all the OMAP processors you can get off-the-shelf are GP devices, i.e. with the TrustZone functions disabled (or else they're processors in production devices such as off-the-shelf mobile phones, for which you don't get the keys). The situation is similar with other SoC manufacturers. Apart from ARM's limited publications (which only cover the common ARM features anyway, and not the chip-specific features such as memory management details, booting and loading trusted code), all documentation about TrustZone features comes under NDA. This is a pity because it precludes independent analysis of these security features or leverage by open-source software.

I'm afraid that if you want to program for a TrustZone device, you'll have to contact a representative of TI or one of their competitors, convince them that your application is something they want to happen, and obtain HS devices, the keys to sign code for your development boards, and the documentation without which you'll have a very hard time.

Answer (score 4):

As of today OP-TEE runs on quite a few devices (see [OP-TEE platforms supported](https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os#3-platforms-supported)) and several of them are development boards readily available. To name a few HiKey, Raspberry Pi3, ARM Juno Board, Freescale i.MX6 variants etc. Either you could pick up one of those or you could simply try it all using QEMU which is [very well supported in OP-TEE](http://www.globalplatform.org/TEEevent/media_center_blog_jbech.asp).

Comment: Yes, things have changed considerable to the positive after 5 years  :)

Answer (score 3):

You can get 45 days trial version for ARM fastmodels. RaspberyPI is supposed to support TrustZone too. www.openvirtualization.org has full open source implementation of ARM TrustZone. ARM is moving away from its proprietary TrustZone APIs to globalplatform API. GlobalPlatform also defines the APIs for Inter process communication etc.

Comment: This is most likely just semantics, but there's no such thing as an open source implementation of ARM TrustZone.  TrustZone is a collection of hardware extensions and modification that support two isolation execution environments.  There is no software implementation of these hardware features.  What openvirtualization provides is a Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) that utilizes TrustZone to isolate the TEE from the regular operating system, i.e. Android or Ubuntu.  So if you get a platform that already has code running in the Secure world, the openvirtualization TEE won't work.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few select boards at this time that do allow development with TrustZone.  As far as general purpose board, the FriendlyARM board is a good start (http://www.friendlyarm.net).  Also, any board with a Cortex A15 processor must have TrustZone available due to the fact that the virtualization extensions can only be utilized from the Normal world.  There may still be a question of whether or not the manufacturer has their own code running in the Secure world, but you can always try.  The Arndale is a good development board, but unfortunately Samsung already has code running in the Secure world, so by the time you get access, you're running in the Normal world.  So if you need Secure world access, look for non-Samsung, Cortex A15 processors.  That'd be your best bet.

It's also worth noting the TI did not technically disable TrustZone.  Instead, the bootrom code transitions the processor into the Normal world prior to switching execution to U-boot.  So it's actually using TrustZone to move to the Normal world, but then doesn't provide a mechanism for moving back to the Secure world.  To prove this, just try to read the SCR and you'll get an undefined exception, which is what will typically happen from the Normal world.  However, if you perform a SMC call, it will execute just as expected (i.e., it switches to the Secure world, but then just switches right back to the Normal world), so it looks like nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

regarding openvirtualization, it can be ported to arm development board like the samsung exynos 4XXX.

you will have access to all source code including the secure os if you use openvirtualization.
but if you just want to develop programs that use the trustzone, I wonder if it is necessary. maybe there are standard driver or api that allow you to do it without worrying about compiling your own secure os?

Answer (score 1):

the best thing you can do is contact parties like Gemalto and the people that brought Mobicore. Note that they will indeed ask you to sign an NDA.

Secondly, you can buy the ARM DS5 development suite. This comes with a lot of documentation including some on trustzone.

Answer (score 1):

You should really take a look at the USB armory from Inverse Path: http://www.inversepath.com/usbarmory.html

It's built on open hardware and open source with full access to Trustzone (you can blow in die fuse to enable secure boot): https://github.com/inversepath/usbarmory

They successfully ran Genode within TZ and Linux in the normal world.